# How to solve limit of $\frac{x^x}{(x-3)^3}$ when x goes to 3?

Tags: limits

This is also home work problem, similar to my previous question. I don't want you to solve it for me, just some tips and tricks would be welcome.

I need to solve limit:

$$\frac{x^x}{(x-3)^3}$$

when $x$ goes to $x_0=3$ but doesn't reach it.

If I put in $3$, then I get $\frac{27}{0}$, which is undeterminate.

If I take derivative I get something very complex, and $(x-3)^4$ in the denominator. In this homework I can't actually use derivative and have to simplify it by other methods.

Any ideas what to do?

Comment: The limit does not exist.

Comment: The top approaches $27$ as you saw. As $x$ approaches $3$ from the right, the bottom approaches $0$ through positive values, so the whole thing blows up. Now check what happens as $x$ approaches $3$ from the left.

Comment: lol it exists. You now how to solve the limit of $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{x}$$

Comment: @AndréNicolas I think the same thing happens? Is there any difference if I approach from left or right? I end up at 3 in both cases?

Comment: @Lolman 1/x is infinity

Comment: @bodacydo No, the limit of $1/x$ as $x\to 0$ is not $\infty$. The limit does not exist, as for $x<0$, the values are negative, and for $x>0$, they are positive.

Comment: As we approach from the left, the thing becomes very large negative.

Comment: I think that it is more correct (and more informative) to say "the limit is $\pm\infty$ " than "there is no limit". The use of "no limit" is more convenient, for exemple, in the case of cos(1/x) for x tending to $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f(x)=\frac{x^x}{(x-3)^3}$$
If you're talking about [L'Hôpital's rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule), Then you cannot use it even if it's allowed to  use in your excercise.

In our case
$$\lim_{x\to3^+}\frac{x^x}{(x-3)^3}\neq\lim_{x\to3^-}\frac{x^x}{(x-3)^3}$$
Hence

> Limit does not exist

**Note:**
[Existence and one-sided limits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_function#Existence_and_one-sided_limits)

It never hurts to plot graphs

[image][image]

**Note:** In both images vertical line is $x=3$ and curve is $f(x)$,Don't forget to look at scale. ( It was almost impossible to show both parts in one image)

Comment: Thanks @digital brain. Yes, I was talking about Lospitahl Rule. What about one-sided limits though?

Comment: @bodacydo Notice the behavior of $f(x)$ near $x=3$.

Comment: @bodacydo I hope it helps

Comment: It helped. Thanks a lot!